# Setting response content type header in JSONP request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, utf-8, jsonp

I have a use case where I make a cross domain JSONP request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=<any_website_url>&callback=?'",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}});
```

It was working fine but I noticed that for Chinese websites data comes garbled. I debugged this and found out that response-header is always set to:

```
Response Header: Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Now this charset ISO-8859-1 is creating a problem. It should have been UTF-8. I basically want to always override this charset to UTF-8. I know I can do this using ajax. I tried using the following code -

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=www.google.com&callback=?'",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}});
```

But this did not fix the problem. I am guessing as JSONP request does not use XHR object, this will not work.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this or if it is even achievable? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that JSONP does not use the XHR object, it uses a `script` tag.

However, this can be done through the jQuery JSONP wrapper using the `scriptCharset` option.

### Excerpt from the [jQuery.ajax docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **scriptCharset**
>
> Type: String
>
> Only applies when the "script" transport is
>   used (e.g., cross-domain requests with "jsonp" or "script" dataType
>   and "GET" type). Sets the `charset` attribute on the script tag used in
>   the request. Used when the character set on the local page is not the
>   same as the one on the remote script.

All you have to do to get jQuery to add the `UTF-8` `charset` attribute to the JSONP `script` tag is add `scriptCharset: 'UTF-8'` to your AJAX settings object.

### Example Code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=<any_website_url>&callback=?'",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  scriptCharset: 'UTF-8',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got to learn something new today. I haven't tried it yet but looks promising from the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

What a jsonp request essentially is is an external javascript file being included using `<script>` tags. Luckily the `<script>`-element has a `charset` attribute which you can set `UTF-8`. This thus looks something like

```
<script 
  src="http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=<any_website_url>&callback=myCallbackFunction"
  charset="UTF-8"
></script>
```

where `myCallbackFunction` has been previously defined and will be called with the requested data. So what you get is

```
<script>
  window.myCallbackFunction = function(data){
  }
  // Dynamically insert the previously describe <script> tag here.
</script>
```

It turns out that this is also directly possible on the `jQuery.ajax` function opts by setting the `scriptCharset` property.

> Only applies when the "script" transport is used (e.g., cross-domain requests with "jsonp" or "script" dataType and "GET" type). Sets the `charset` attribute on the script tag used in the request. Used when the character set on the local page is not the same as the one on the remote script.